# Is this function decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that the following function is decreasing when $x>0$
$$f(x)=\frac{(x+1)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}-(x+1)^2\arcsin\Big(\frac{1}{x+1}\Big)$$
but calculating its derivative I don't succed in proving this result.

Comment: So what did you get as $f'(x)$?

Comment: $$f'(x)=(x+1)\bigg[\frac{2x^2+4x-1}{(x^2+2x)\sqrt{x^2+2x}}-2\arcsin\Big(\frac{1}{x+1}\Big)\bigg]$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f'(x) = \dfrac{3(x+1)-\dfrac{(x+1)^3}{(x+2)x}}{\sqrt{x(x+2)}}-2(x+1)\arcsin(\dfrac{1}{1+x})$

Since $1+x>0$,thus we just prove

$\dfrac{3-\dfrac{(1+x)^2}{(x+2)x}}{\sqrt{x(x+2}}-2\arcsin(\dfrac{1}{x+1})\le 0$

Since $\arcsin(\dfrac{1}{1+x})\ge \dfrac{1}{1+x}$, thus

we just prove

$\dfrac{3-\dfrac{(1+x)^2}{(x+2)x}}{\sqrt{x(x+2)}}-\dfrac{2}{x+1}\le 0$

which is equivalent to

$3-\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{x(x+2)}-\dfrac{2\sqrt{x(x+2)}}{x+1}\le 0$

take $u = \dfrac{1+x}{\sqrt{x(x+2)}}$, then

we just have to show

$3-u^2-\dfrac{2}{u}\le 0$.

AM-GM Inequality

$u^2+\dfrac{1}{u}+\dfrac{1}{u}\ge 3\sqrt[3]{1}=3$

And we know $u\neq 1$, thus the equality cannot be achieved.